# queryHash field not available in mongos slow query logs

Tags: mongodb, slow-log, mongodb-4.0

Mongodb V4.2 has introduced [queryHash](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/query-plans/#queryhash) in slow query logs to identify slow queries with same query shape. While this `queryHash` is available in slow query logs in `mongod` logs (shard server), it is not present in any of the slow query logs on my `mongos` server.

**Mongod log**

```
{"t":{"$date":"2021-01-09T01:45:27.821+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"COMMAND",  "id":51803,   "ctx":"conn143447","msg":"Slow query","attr":{"type":"command","ns":"xxxx.collection","command":{"find":"collection","filter":{"entityId":"xxxx.ru"},"projection":{"crawlerDataId":0},"sort":{"sourceUpdatedAt":-1},"readConcern":{"provenance":"implicitDefault"},"limit":100,"runtimeConstants":{"localNow":{"$date":"2021-01-09T01:45:27.689Z"},"clusterTime":{"$timestamp":{"t":1610156727,"i":93}}},"_use44SortKeys":true,"shardVersion":[{"$timestamp":{"t":89277,"i":1}},{"$oid":"5cb57c9eafd72c1e06b5c433"}],"clientOperationKey":{"$uuid":"56e5a665-9162-4e1d-a368-165e592d59de"},"lsid":{"id":{"$uuid":"a15a9b9c-bb4f-4d1f-8770-08b64b28ad2b"},"uid":{"$binary":{"base64":"6ikS+z/HSNSwWB1ARioMqqzdlxOaNtFe+gViCoYwELs=","subType":"0"}}},"$clusterTime":{"clusterTime":{"$timestamp":{"t":1610156727,"i":93}},"signature":{"hash":{"$binary":{"base64":"7GLR2+4NQu2cWHpgqx31zmi28NE=","subType":"0"}},"keyId":6875251194940358707}},"$audit":{"$impersonatedUsers":[{"user":"xxxx","db":"xxxx"}],"$impersonatedRoles":[{"role":"readWrite","db":"xxxx"}]},"$client":{"driver":{"name":"mongo-java-driver","version":"3.9.1"},"os":{"type":"Linux","name":"Linux","architecture":"amd64","version":"5.4.0-1021-aws"},"platform":"Java/Private Build/1.8.0_265-8u265-b01-0ubuntu2~20.04-b01","mongos":{"host":"xxxx:27017","client":"xxxxx","version":"4.4.1"}},"$configServerState":{"opTime":{"ts":{"$timestamp":{"t":1610156725,"i":79}},"t":12}},"$db":"xxxx"},"planSummary":"IXSCAN { entityId: \"hashed\" }","keysExamined":73,"docsExamined":73,"hasSortStage":true,"cursorExhausted":true,"numYields":8,"nreturned":73,"queryHash":"F305D754","planCacheKey":"42D383C3","reslen":397160,"locks":{"ReplicationStateTransition":{"acquireCount":{"w":9}},"Global":{"acquireCount":{"r":9}},"Database":{"acquireCount":{"r":9}},"Collection":{"acquireCount":{"r":9}},"Mutex":{"acquireCount":{"r":3}}},"readConcern":{},"storage":{"data":{"bytesRead":5215788,"timeReadingMicros":129685}},"protocol":"op_msg","durationMillis":132}}
```

**Mongos log**

```
{"t":{"$date":"2020-12-31T02:19:33.680+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"COMMAND",  "id":51803,   "ctx":"conn128","msg":"Slow query","attr":{"type":"command","ns":"xxxx.companyPriority","command":{"find":"companyPriority","filter":{"_id":{"$in":[{"$oid":"5319df10e4b0f7e16602a313"}]}},"$db":"xxxx","$clusterTime":{"clusterTime":{"$timestamp":{"t":1609381171,"i":2}},"signature":{"hash":{"$binary":{"base64":"C2cNRe4vAhiBs97T6VYXIYYU1Ck=","subType":"0"}},"keyId":6877905033757720578}},"lsid":{"id":{"$uuid":"ba72a15f-2568-43e9-8c9a-abd7bd2aa6be"}}},"nShards":1,"cursorExhausted":true,"numYields":0,"nreturned":1,"reslen":278,"protocol":"op_msg","durationMillis":2007}}
```

`"queryHash":"F305D754"` is present in `mongod` log and no `queryHash` key in `mongos`
The documentation nowhere mentions about the `queryHash` availability (or the absence of it) on `mongos` server logs separately. Is this expected behaviour or some configuration changes are required to get `queryHash` in `mongos`  logs?

Note: `mongos` and `mongod` both are running on version `4.4.1`

Comment: Per the issue you raised in the MongoDB Jira issue tracker (https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-53859), it looks like this may be a useful logging improvement. Those interested should watch & upvote the Jira issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is expected behaviour by design i.e currently `queryHash` is not available for `mongos` logs. As mentioned in the comment to the question, this has been picked as a [improvement](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-53859) for future release. Closing the question.